# Is there a GUI way to copy a folder's path in MATLAB?

Tags: windows, path, gui, matlab

Is there a way to easily copy the name of a folder's full path within MATLAB, from the MATLAB folder window, into a MATLAB script or command window?

Dragging with mouse would be very nice, but I guess it runs `cd()`. Maybe we can somehow change its behavior?

Or is there any extension/toolbox etc., that can make this easier?

Thanks for any help !

I'm asking for 64-bit Windows (7 and) 8, MATLAB R2015b

Comment: copy it from where?

Comment: From the folder itself. Maybe "import" could be a better word. I just want to drag a folder (with mouse) and I want a variable created like `x = 'C:\Documents\MyFolder'`

Comment: What OS? Do you mean from Windows Explorer? Please be a lot more specific.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers yes I am asking Windows. I added the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Matlab, I find the easiest way is just to open a script/function file in that folder, if the folder I'm interested in has such a file. Then in the list of open files, I right click on that file's name, and "Copy Full Path to Clipboard"

Another way is to drag the path to the command window, and that will indeed change the current folder. However, you can then use the back arrow on the address bar to return to your previous directory. And then you've got the text in your command window to copy and paste.

If you're going to be doing this a lot, it's probably better if at all possible to work out an algorithm to do the directory selection that you are doing manually, and program up the bit to obtain directory paths. Or even to rearrange your directories to make it easier for your program to do its work by just using relative paths.

In Windows Explorer, to get the path of the current windows explorer window into the clipboard, just click once in the blank space in the address bar. This will convert the text in there into a path, already selected. Just press Ctrl-C to put this in your clipboard. Then just paste into Matlab (or any other app that's expecting plain text)

Comment: Yes that's usually how I solve it, but it still requires to 1) right click, 2) "show in explorer", 3) select the address bar, etc.. When done repeatedly, it can cost a lot of time, so I wondered if there is an easier way for this.

Comment: You said you wanted to copy it "from the folder itself". I took that to mean that you already had windows explorer open. Please be clearer and more specific about what you are asking. If you're having to do this lots of times, it would be best if you can describe *why*, as maybe a completely diffferent approach would be a better solution.

Comment: Oh, ok, I did not anticipate this confusion, sorry about that. I mean to drag the folder from the window to the left of the workspace (not sure what it's called). "Matlab's explorer window"?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama ah, now I understand. Question and answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is pretty good for me. Although it's not directly the folder's path, it will do. Thanks :)